# Is it possible to cast one function type to another function type that takes same parameter but different return type?

Tags: c++, pointers

I just saw one line of code

```
 if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)){
 }
```

I did not quite get it,
then i looked up the function definition.

```
GLFWglproc glfwGetProcAddress(const char *procname) 
// which means this is a function takes a pointer and returns something
```

that something is

```
typedef void(* GLFWglproc) (void)
// a function pointer
```

ok the glfwGetProcAddress takes a pointer and returns a function pointer

however when i looked the code (GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress , what does it mean?

```
typedef void* (* GLADloadproc)(const char *name);
```

the GLADloadproc is also a function pointer.

the outter function

```
void gladLoadGLLoader(GLADloadproc);
```

is just a normal function. it takes a function pointer , do something with it and returns nothing.

ok , so , when invoking gladLoadGLLoader, the inside is a function pointer, that means (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress is a function pointer pointing to some function . it never invoked the glfwGetProcAddress,

however, when i do this

```
if (!gladLoadGLLoader(static_cast<GLADloadproc>(glfwGetProcAddress))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
main.cpp:46:27: error: static_cast from 'GLFWglproc (*)(const char *)' (aka
  'void (*(*)(const char *))()') to 'GLADloadproc' (aka 'void *(*)(const
  char *)') is not allowed
```

where am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. No, not with a `static_cast`. And finally, you shouldn't use that pointer to call anything, because you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: Then entire Win32 is undefined behavior because you have to cast pointers returned by GetProcAddress to call a function from DLL.

Comment: @MinorThreat - Rubbish. Using a pointer of the **correct** type is not UB. Get your facts straight.

Comment: GetProcAddress always returns int(__stdcall*)(). However, if function from DLL have a signature, for example, void* (__cdecl*)(char*, char*), you have to cast it.

Comment: @MinorThreat - And if you think I meant the cast itself is UB, you completely misunderstood me.

Comment: @StoryTeller : The whole of Win32 *is* UB (as far as the C++ standard goes).  The standard does not define what `#include <windows.h>` does.  (The same applies to posix headers too.)  In practise, one can't write useful programs without some UB (which is defined by the implementation).

Comment: As MS use their own compiler to build Windows, they can define anything they like and *make* it work.

Comment: @MartinBonner - Yes and no. The standard doesn't define any externally provided header. But to argue that using such a header is UB is nonsense. As for the implementation specific parts of `windows.h`, the code is not pure standard C++, but what does that have to do with it? Abusing function pointers is not something windows programming will guarantee you to work correctly. You still need to know what you are doing, thus you aren't operating in UB land.

Comment: _"Any pointer to function can be converted to a pointer to a different function type. Calling the function through a pointer to a different function type is undefined, but converting such pointer back to pointer to the original function type yields the pointer to the original function."_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where am i wrong?

You used the wrong cast for the job. A `static_cast` is very strict in its static type checking. The two pointer types are unrelated, so a static cast would be ill-formed.

What you *may* use to cast function pointer types is a `reinterpret_cast`. Beware however, that short of a C-style cast (which will try to guarantee some cast is performed), a reinterpret cast is a very blunt tool. Don't use it unless you really need it, because it forgoes a lot of static type checking.

Finally, only use the resulting pointer type to call the function if you know for sure that it matches the functions declared prototype. Otherwise you'd get undefined behavior.