Warning when casting FARPROC from GetProcAddress to specific function pointer type in MinGW-w64
I am using MinGW-w64 and trying to dynamically import a function from a DLL using GetProcAddress. The function I want to import has the following signature:
__declspec(dllexport) double __cdecl func(double t, unsigned int n);

To retrieve the function, I am using GetProcAddress from WIN32 API as follows:
typedef double (__cdecl *TYPE_FUNCTION)(double, unsigned int);
TYPE_FUNCTION func_ptr = (TYPE_FUNCTION) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "func");

However, I receive the following:
warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'double (*)(double, unsigned int)'

Is this warning something I should be concerned about? If so, how can I safely cast or call the function? Would the cast cause any potential issues at runtime?

Is this warning something I should be concerned about? - no. but is correct. but exist better solution, without type cast and typedef

@Sam your code is perfectly fine, you can safely ignore the warning in this case. Disable the warning if you don't want to see it.

All function pointers types have the same representation and can be converted to each other. What matters is that a function call matches the function definition.

Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77335918/5264491

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365371/ It is asked for C++, but the underlying issue applies to C, too. As long as the final call uses the correct pointer type that matches the original function, there is no problem casting function pointers from one type to another. Lots of libraries are built around this very premise and would break if it didn't work.

@IanAbbott, yes that was help full, thanks.
And RemyLebeau, ok, that sounds great, thanks also.
Maybe I could add, that I was worried about ABI issues with passing arguments and returning values, but maybe this is an unrelated topic with warning itself. In other words, I'm not sure, if it is possible to break the ABI of the imported dll function by performing a wrong casting.

@Sam possible to break the ABI of the imported dll function by performing a wrong casting you can break ABI by performing a wrong declaration of function. if your declaration not equal of actual function signature. but by wrong casting - this is how ? you can damage binary value maybe, if cast change binary value. but not ABI. and your reinterpret cast not change binary value returned from GetProcAddress. despite i think possible do this in more nice way

use
__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl func(double t, unsigned int n);

and
PVOID __imp_func;

(in case c++ declare both as EXTERN_C or extern "C" )
and finally
__imp_func = GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "func");

so we not need any typedef and cast
explanation:
when we declare function func with __declspec(dllimport) attribute, compiler declare variable extern PVOID __imp_func; (add __imp_) prefix to decorated function func name. and when you call func compiler generate code call __imp_func; so all what we need - implement PVOID __imp_func;. in case static link - the __imp_func will be inside some lib file. if you use dynamic linking - simply implement PVOID __imp_func; by self (without extern) and assign it value from GetProcAddress (or LdrGetProcedureAddress). note - this is for x64 mangling.
for x86 this will be PVOID _imp__func (because __cdecl - func will be transformed to _func and variable x transformed to _x so PVOID _imp__func generate __imp__func symbol in x86)
if use __stdcall - will be PVOID _imp__func@12 (__imp__func@12 symbol). we can not declare
PVOID _imp__func@12; already. but we can use asm for this. or if use CL (more known as msvc) compiler (latest versions) we can use
__identifier keyword with
#pragma warning(disable: 4483) // Allow use of __identifier

so code in case x86 and if api was __stdcall
#pragma warning(disable: 4483) // Allow use of __identifier

__declspec(dllimport) double __stdcall func(double t, unsigned int n);

#define __imp_func __identifier("_imp__func@12")

PVOID __imp_func; // = GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "func");


Wow, in 30 years of programming with the Win32 API, I have never once seen anyone use GetProcAddress() in this manner. Also, note the __identifier() you link to is a Microsoft C++/CLI extension, but the OP is using MingGW not MSVC.

PVOID is a void*, the generic object pointer type, only to be used with object pointers. If following the C or C++ standards, you can't use that type with function pointers - that's a non-compatible pointer conversion and undefined behavior.

@Lundin - __imp_func is not used in C/C++ code here, it's a placeholder for the function pointer expected by the __declspec(dllimport) tag, it works because it's named _imp[function name], it's a linker trick.

@RemyLebeau very strange. from my point of view it is an elementary thing, but I have never seen anyone use it except me. I do not understand how this can be. __identifier is needed only in case of x86.

@SimonMourier exactly. for every imported function we need somewhere save pointer to it body. and it saved in named variable __imp_[function name]. and main point - we can access this variable by name.

@Lundin Interestingly, POSIX has dlsym() which returns a void * and could be the address of an object or a function.

@IanAbbott POSIX is very far from well-designed...

@Lundin __imp_[func] hold address of fucntion. i assign address to it. compiler use it during call to func. so what is wrong/undefined/etc here ?

@RbMm In theory you might not get the correct calling convention, objects may have different address sizes/ranges than functions etc etc. If you know how the ABI treats pointers for a very specific system then you can get away with it. On many systems you would get a hardware trap if trying to execute code from data space or trying to access contents in the program space.

@Lundin - but this already absolute another question. this is question of interpreatation of result GetProcAddress. for which function (or data) it point, which signature of function, etc. and in any case we can mistake here. and so what ? this not related to question or my answer at all

If the return address from GetProcAddress does not fit inside a void* then the program will fail. I don't know what guarantees the ABI makes between function pointers and object pointers. Is there any particularly reason why you can't use something like a void (*)(void) function pointer as placeholder? That one is far more likely to have the same representation.

@Lundin If the return address from GetProcAddress does not fit inside a void* this is imposible. the compliler itself use __imp_[func] for all imported api. if something wrong in what i wrote - all windows will crash

@Lundin and look like you dont understand that extern PVOID __imp_func; not my declaration. this is compiler use this declaration. i simply implement it. or will be error - unresolved external symbol __imp_func

@IanAbbott POSIX also adds this:  "Note that conversion from a void * pointer to a function pointer as in:
fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");
is not defined by the ISO C standard. This standard requires this conversion to work correctly on conforming implementations."

@RbMm look like you dont understand that extern PVOID __imp_func; not my declaration.  What are you basing your assumption that __imp_func has type PVOID on?

@SimonMourier See my above comment.  What is the basis for assuming __imp_func is actually defined as a pointer to void?

@AndrewHenle it have the pointer size , so exactly the sizeof(void*). And hold the address of some point in memory. So this is from binary view exactly the pointer to void. You can declare it in another way, with save size. And what will be different? I say no any different. If you think that it can be, can you show and explain this ?

@AndrewHenle and maybe it not declared in c/c++ at all. But declared in asm extern __imp_func : QWORD ( DWORD in case 32 bit ) . What in this case ? All what need - use variable with exact name and size , which will be hold binary representation of pointer. All other - no difference. No difference between bool (*__imp_func)(int, char*) and void* __imp_func. Or will be very interesting know example or explain in which case it will be different in code binary behaviour

@RbMm NO.  Please read 6.3.2.3 Pointers, paragraph 1 and paragraph 8 and then explain where a conversion from void * to a function pointer is defined.  The POSIX standard even states "conversion from a void * pointer to a function pointer ... is not defined by the ISO C standard".  In the absence of supporting documentation that means this answer is undefined behavior.  Full stop.  "All what need - use variable with exact name and size" is not true.

Not observing a failure is not the same as correct code that's guaranteed to work.

@AndrewHenle i have another opinion here. also look (or write test by self) - https://gist.github.com/rbmm/36c3269e6bb196b4a47d8bf1cff7861f .  the EXTRN __imp_?func@@YANNI@Z:PROC in asm. this mean it initially defined in asm only, never in c/c++ (because i not view how variable posible declare for have PROC type). and all this c++ ... only show problems with the wording in c++ itself. no more.

@RbMm So you posted code that invokes undefined behavior to github?  What does that prove?  Again - not observing failure does not mean the behavior is defined.  If you want to accept undefined behavior in your code, that's on you.  Others have higher standards.  If the behavior is defined somewhere in MS documentation, find it and add it to your answer.  Note that what you are doing is defined under POSIX - and I even provided the link.  If you're going to claim it's defined behavior, you need to provide the documentation that defines the behavior.

@AndrewHenle i absolute not agree with you and not view any UB here at all. code use pointer size variable ( __imp_?func@@YANNI@Z in concrete case ) for call func (or full name ?func@@YANNI@Z ) and so what ? what is wrong here ? where UB. how at all this code can fail? be wrong ?

@AndrewHenle all your UB at all internal for c/c++ termin. i here not do any cast, any type punning at all. what concrete operator, line is UB ? all work on binary/asm level, under c/c++.

@AndrewHenle - this is really not about C/C++ or even not about any language, but "just" about how Windows "runtime" links code (dynamically) to dll files, and support MSVC has for it (that maybe some other compilers also mimic), partially documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-function-calls-using-declspec-dllimport but one needs to connect the dot to have it work with GetProcAddress, this is what RbMm exposed. It's really a "Windows/Microsoft only"  linker trick.

@SimonMourier agree. this really out of any language. However, even if we stay within the language, it seems to me that the formal rules of C/C++ have problems with justifying pointer casting. How can this be done in C++, like in QueryInterface etc.? Casting via reinterpret_cast and union. I have an opinion here that differs from the opinion of the absolute majority, but this is a separate and endless topic

@AndrewHenle This conversion is described as a "common extension" in Annex J (C11). MSVC implements this with well-defined behavior (so, no UB). Other compilers targeting the Windows ABI necessarily must implement this conversion with the same semantics as the Windows ABI requires it.

@IInspectable Yes, it's a common extension.  But merely saying it's not UB without documentation or at least stating it depends on an extension is incomplete and potentially misleading.

@AndrewHenle again, UB in what ? Which operator, expression, etc is UB in concrete code ? Assign __imp_func = GetProcAddress ? But this is exactly not UB. And no any other code here at all. __imp_func not used anywhere in c/c++ code. How it used internally by compiler - this already out of language layer
